# Display alternate toString() Method with custom cell editor

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, tablecelleditor

I am creating what is basically I copy of excel. The user enters data into a JTable, then that data is parsed, processed, and it displays the toString() method for the appropriate type of Cell, which is an interface that I have created several subclasses for.

When a user starts to edit a FormulaCell, I would like the cell to display the formula retrieved by a getFormula() method rather than the evaluated formula retrieved by the toString() method.

I explored custom cell editors, but I could not figure out which method to override. I think the code would be something like this inside of a custom cell editor or whatever I need create:

```
if (cell instanceof FormulaCell) {
  startingText = (FormulaCell) cell).getFormula();
}
```

Each cell in the JTable has a different class, so I can't really override DefaultTableModel's getColumnClass() Method and set a custom cell editor for the Formula Cell class.

For reference, here's the main part of my program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

import cell.*;

public class Program extends JPanel {

    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private JTable table;

    public static final int ASCII_SHIFT = 64, HEIGHT = 10, WIDTH = 7, ROW_HEIGHT = 40;
    public static final Dimension BUTTON_SIZE = new Dimension(70,30),
            TABLE_SIZE = new Dimension(780, 400);

    //makes program runnable
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {

        //sets title and does everything necessary to
        //create and show the GUI
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextExcel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Program contentPane = new Program();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Program() {

        //sets the layout
        super(new BorderLayout());

        //creates a String[] for column headers
        String[] letter = new String[WIDTH];
        for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
            byte[] character = {(byte) (i + ASCII_SHIFT + 1)};
            letter[i] = new String(character);
        }

        //creates the table
        model = new DefaultTableModel(letter, HEIGHT);
        table = new JTable(model);

        //makes a cell parse the input when enter is pressed
        Action action = new AbstractAction()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                TableCellListener tcl = (TableCellListener)e.getSource();
                int row = tcl.getRow();
                int column = tcl.getColumn();
                String input = (String) model.getValueAt(row, column);
                parse(input, row, column);
            }
        };
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        TableCellListener tcl = new TableCellListener(table, action);

        //centers the headers
        JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
        header.setDefaultRenderer(new HeaderRenderer(table));
        header.setReorderingAllowed(false);

        //centers text in cells
        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, centerRenderer);

        //sets the height of rows
        for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
            table.setRowHeight(i, ROW_HEIGHT);
        }

        //creates a scroll-pane for the table and numbers the rows
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        JTable rowTable = new RowNumberTable(table);
        scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(rowTable);
        scrollPane.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER, rowTable.getTableHeader());
        add(scrollPane);

        //sizes the table
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(TABLE_SIZE);

        //creates a panel to place buttons
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        //creates a button to clear the table
        JButton clearButton = new JButton("clear");
        clearButton.setPreferredSize(BUTTON_SIZE);
        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                clearTable();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(clearButton);

        //message displayed when help button is pressed
        String helpMessage = "To construct a Cell, double click a cell, "
                + "enter the argument, and press enter.\n"
                + "To clear a Cell, press the \"clear\" button.\n\n"
                + "There are 5 subclasses of Cell:\n"
                + "StringCell, DateCell, NumberCell, "
                + "FormulaCell, and SumAvgCell.\n"
                + "All numbers are displayed as Fractions and all Cells displaying numbers extend\n"
                + "NumberCell. Any double entered will be converted to a Fraction.\n\n"
                + "* StringCells display text and are simply typed into the cell. If an input is\n"
                + "invalid for all other types of Cell, it will become a StringCell.\n"
                + "* DateCells display dates in the form (Month Day, Year). They are constructed\n"
                + "in the form (m/d/yy) or (m/d/yyyy). Extra zeroes in m and d are not necessary.\n"
                + "* NumberCells simply display Fractions and can be constructed from a double,\n"
                + "int, standard fraction, or mixed fraction.\n"
                + "* FormulaCells are constructed from any combination of operations(+-*/%),\n"
                + "values, parantheses, and references. Order of operations is supported. An\n"
                + "example of a valid input would be \"(A1 + 4.4 * b3) % C2 - 3_6/8\".\n"
                + "* SumAvgCells can be used to find the sum or average of a rectangular area of\n"
                + "cells. They are constructed in the form (command reference - reference).\n"
                + "The first reference is the top-left corner and the second reference is the\n"
                + "bottom-right corner. An example of a valid input would be \"sum A1 - B2\".\n"
                + "Another valid input would be \"avg C1 - C8\".";

        //creates a help button to display a helpful message
        JButton helpButton = new JButton("help");
        helpButton.setPreferredSize(BUTTON_SIZE);
        helpButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getComponent(0), helpMessage, "HelpBox", 1);
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(helpButton);

        //creates a panel to place the table
        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        tablePanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //adds the button and table panels
        add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    //parses user input to set a cell value
    public void parse(String input, int row, int column) {

        //initializes cell to be set
        Cell cell = null;

        //helpful variables
        String ref = "([a-g]\\d*)";
        String dub = "([-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d*)";
        String frac = "((\\d+_\\d+/\\d+)|(\\d+/\\d+))";

        //parses the input according to regular expressions
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        if (input.matches("(" + ref + "|" + dub + "|" + frac + ")"
                + "( [-+*/%] (" + ref + "|" + dub + "|" + frac + "))+")) {
            cell = new FormulaCell(input, model);
        }
        else if (input.matches("((sum)|(avg)) " + ref + " - " + ref)) {
            cell = new SumAvgCell(input, model);
        }
        else if (input.matches(dub + "|" + frac)) {
            cell = new NumberCell(input);
        }
        else if (input.matches("(\\d{1}|\\d{2})/(\\d{1}|\\d{2})/(\\d{2}|\\d{4})")) {
            cell = new DateCell(input);
        }
        else {
            cell = new StringCell(input);
        }

        //sets the cell value
        model.setValueAt(cell, row, column);
    }

    //sets all cell values to null
    public void clearTable() {
        for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
                model.setValueAt(null, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance on how to create the desired behavior would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a method, for example `getDetailedText()`, in `Cell` interface which returns the text which will be used in cell editor. Then return formula from this method in `FormulaCell`. For other cells you can return `toString()`.

Cell interface:

```
public interface Cell {

     public String getDetailedText();
}
```

FormulaCell:

```
public class FormulaCell implements Cell {

    public String getDetailedText() {
         return formula;
    }
}
```

Other Cells (if you want to display another text for each cell just return here):

```
public class OtherCell implements Cell {

    public String getDetailedText() {
         return toString();
    }
}
```

Then create a cell editor and set it as default editor to the table.

Default cell editor:

```
public class MyDefaultCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    public MyDefaultCellEditor() {
        super(new JTextField());
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row,
            int column) {
        JTextField textField = (JTextField) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
        Cell cell = (Cell) value;

        textField.setText(cell.getEditorText());
        return textField;
    }
}
```

Set to the table:

```
table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new MyDefaultCellEditor());
```

Comment: When I ran it, the getTableCellEditorComponent(...) method endlessly called itself, resulting in a StackOverflowError. This may or may not be helpful, but I am using a custom cell listener called TableCellListener, which I found on Java Tips Weblog.

Comment: I just forgot the add `super.`. Now updated that part.

Comment: Great; that fixed it! The only other complication was that the call to super needed to be cast to a JTextField.